# Why should we use the -O2 flag when there's -O3 for g++?

Tags: optimization, g++, compiler-optimization

I've seen a lot of people use -O2 when compiling their C++ code, but why would you not use -O3 instead? My assumption is that it makes the code more optimised/faster compared to using -O2 unless there's some caveats that I'm missing here, but I'm not sure the reasoning behind why using -O3 isn't the standard or why it's not widely used for compiling with g++ (at least from my observations).

Comment: I guess O3 takes more time to compile so before production it could save engineering time to use O2 and just make it O3 after production. Better engineering run-time before launch + better app run-time after launch.

Comment: Historically, `-O3` had a bad reputation for sometimes slowing things down because of bloated code.  It hasn't enabled loop unrolling for years without `-fprofile-use` PGO, but does still enable auto-vectorization (but that's part of -O2 in GCC12 and later)

Comment: @JérômeRichard - Kind of a duplicate, but the 9 year old answers there were already outdated at the time in recommending against `-O3`.  It could be time for a fresh canonical.  (Basile's answer there is useful, showing that as early as GCC4.8 major steps had been made to make `-O3` less likely to be slower.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I partially agree. I think it is better to update old post that are widely seen rather than creating duplicates. If the alternative post would not be famous, then I would fully agree. (I did not expect the bot to close the question based on my unique vote though).

Comment: @PeterCordes Btw, this is not so rare auto-vectorization make the code slower because the compiler wrongly assume that the loop is hot (though not usual either). Having auto-vectorization enabled in `-O2` will certainly cause some code to be slower because of that. I guess they did that because many people used `-O2` for no real reasons resulting in many code not being vectorized... But the real issue was not to use `-O3` or at least `-ftree-vectorize`. Do you have any information about this choice?

Comment: @JérômeRichard: No, I just know it changed; I haven't looked for discussion that led up to it.  Agreed that it may hurt front-end throughput sometimes, especially with `char` arrays with massively bloated 31 iterations of cleanup fully peeled like GCC likes to do, unless they fixed that recently to keep the cleanup rolled up.